# Reschedule meeting due to the unavailability of one participant

Tags: grammar, sentence, email

I'd like to reschedule the meeting due to the unavailability of one of the participants. He's an important element for the meeting. I am looking for a sample e-mail to inform all participants that the meeting will be postponed by two hours.

Comment: This site does not provide a writing service. You need to restrict your question to something objective.

Comment: Try here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm a member of the workplace.stackexchange.com as well, I was not sure where to request such service.
Thank you for your feedback (y)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a request for a writing template rather than a question about a particular issue of usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Postpone* is certainly the right word.

> Because X is unavailable, the meeting has been postponed two hours.

You could be more specific about the date and time of the meeting.

> Because X is unavailable, the meeting has been postponed until July
> 16, 2020 at 5:00 p.m.

I like BoldBen's suggestion:

> Because X is unavailable, the meeting scheduled for 3:00 p.m. on July 16, 2020 has been
> postponed until 5:00 p.m. on the same day.

Comment: Also a good ides to include brief details of the meeting which is being postponed to avoid confusion with other meetings. For instance "The campaign meeting scheduled for 3:00  on July 16 2020 has been postponed until 5:00 on the same day because X is unavailable."

Comment: @BoldBen, fair enough!

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback! indeed, including brief details is important especially when participants are too many and we do not know their calendar.
I'll take your advice (y)

Comment: @Srisaila That's the fruit of bitter experience!

Comment: @BoldBen, I agree.